# Encoding trouble in mail function php

Tags: php, email, encoding, utf-8

I am trying so send email with html body, I form it with entries from DB and everything okay, when i check composed message using

```
echo $message;
```

I see great composed text without any errors, but after sending it using mail() function, I have trouble with only 1 symbol.

All page and all data in utf-8, header set to utf as well:

```
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
```

echo result:
[image: after echo]

gmail result:
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Just curios.. why do you have \r\n in your charset?

Comment: Could be double encoding.. because Gmail already has charset set?

Comment: \r\n because I have another lines after

Comment: i thought about double enconding, but gmail can show it plain, and i have the same error, I thinks it happens when gmail gets my email, but i want understand what to do to avoid it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution
Added to headers and remove any charset

```
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . "\r\n";
```

And do that with all my message:

```
$message = rtrim(chunk_split(base64_encode($message)));
```

Now everything works!